# PHP Export Excel from mysql DateTime issue

Tags: php, mysql, excel, time, export

First of all i have the following mysql table ( sold_items_records ) as follows

```
item_no    qty    price   date        time
x1         2      10      2014-4-21   2014-4-21 00:8:20
x2         4      12      2014-4-21   2014-4-21 00:8:20
x3         1      15      2014-4-22   2014-4-22 00:10:55
x1         2      11      2014-4-22   2014-4-22 01:11:40
x1         2      11      2014-4-22   2014-4-22 01:11:40
```

The structures for date is (date) and for time (datetime).

- The next step is to export the above table to an Excel format .xls based on **time** ! so here is the PHP code below :

  ```
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  require_once ('Classes/PHPExcel.php');

  // Create new PHPExcel object
  $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

  // Set document properties
  $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Maarten Balliauw")
                               ->setLastModifiedBy("Maarten Balliauw")
                               ->setTitle("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
                               ->setSubject("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
                               ->setDescription("Test document for Office 2007 XLSX, generated using PHP classes.")
                               ->setKeywords("office 2007 openxml php")
                               ->setCategory("Test result file");




  $query = "SELECT * from sold_items_records ORDER BY time";
  $result = mysql_query($query);

  while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
  if ( !isset($curtime) || $curtime != $row['time'] ) {              
  $curtime = $row['time'];

  $query2 = "SELECT item_no,qty,price,date,time from sold_items_records where time = '".$curtime."'";
  $result2 = mysql_query($query2);



  //Excuting Values from Mysql to Excel
  $row2 = 2; // 1-based index
  while($row_data2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) {

  echo $row_data2['time'];
  $col2 = 0;
  //Row Headers
  $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
              ->setCellValue('A1', 'Item No')
              ->setCellValue('B1', 'QTY')
              ->setCellValue('C1', 'Price')
              ->setCellValue('D1', 'Date')
          ->setCellValue('E1', 'Time');
  //Row Values
      foreach($row_data2 as $key2=>$value2) {
          $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col2, $row2, $value2);
          $col2++;
      }
      $row2++;
  }





  // Rename worksheet

  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');


  // Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
  $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);


  //Check if File Name Exists
  $name = 'C:/Sales-'.date("d-m-Y",strtotime($row['time'])).'.xls';
  $index = 1;
  while(file_exists($name)) {
    $name = $name.'--'.$index.".xls";
    $index++;
  }




  $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
  $objWriter->save($name);




  }
  }
  ```

The output Result needed is to have multiple excel file based on Grouping time...By that i mean is to have file named as A) (Sale-2014-4-21)  B) (Sale-2014-4-22) and (Sale-2014-4-22---1) Yes two dates the same because the TIME is different for the SAME date.

when opening the excel file for each, the File A) show the correct items x1 and x2...While for File B) it will show X3 X1 and X1... Which is not what i needed, instead it should be showing only X3...Same goes for File C) the result will be X1 X1 and X3...Which it should only show X1 and X1...

This is one challenging Question to be honest, I've spent 5 days trying to find out why...Luckily I've tried using alternative way as CSV format the result was 100% true as needed..But when i go back to Excel format the time seems to mess up or it might be ignoring the time.

So my guess its time format in Excel, Any ideas how to force excel to read the whole time row?

Thanks

Comment: What is your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: I don't see any conversion of dates or times to Excel timestamps, or any formatting of cells to date or time formats.... where are you doing this in your code?

Comment: @MarkBaker Oh i see, Could you please just help me out more on how to use the conversion ? Thanks

Comment: @Strawberry I have auto increment id before item_no but it doesn't change the output.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `$row_data2['date']` and `$row_data2['time']` are formatted date strings (in a format recognised by PHP's `DateTime` objects, to convert to an Excel timestamp:

```
$excelDateStamp = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel(
    new DateTime($row_data2['date'])
);
```

and

```
$excelTimeStamp = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel(
    new DateTime($row_data2['time'])
);
```

To set date formatting for a PHPExcel cell:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('A1')
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode('yyyy-m-d');
```

or

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('A1')
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode('yyyy-m-d h:m:ss');
```